# How to create swipe animation like Instagram stories?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-animation

I'm trying to implement horizontal list view like Instagram stories and I implemented the list view but I have no idea on how to animate like Instagram stories when the user swipes the list item. Thanks. [image: Sample animation]

Comment: Please, take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask. You should avoid to ask this kind of questions here. Do some research by yourself and when you get stuck in some step, then come back and ask question where you can show us what you did and where do you think is a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this by using fragments and set the transition animation between the fragments using this library (https://github.com/kakajika/FragmentAnimations). The other option is to create your own custom list view that will behave like you want.